# why Setter Getter class variable only gets the last object from JSON, android,recyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, getter-setter

I just want to know why my Setter Getter class variable only gets the last object from JSON? it is supposed to fetch all json objects to setter getter variable so that it could transfer it to recyclerview.

Here is part of the Code, Im a begginer, pls help

```
 JSONArray json = req
                    .getJSONArray("worldpopulation");


            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonOb = json
                        .getJSONObject(i);
                setterGetterClass = new SuperHeroes(jsonOb.getInt(Configg.TAG_rank),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_country),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_population),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_flag));

                Log.d("tag", setterGetterClass.getcountry().toString());
                Log.d("show: ", setterGetterClass.toString());
            }

            Log.d("parseData: ", setterGetterClass.toString());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: what else would you think could happen?

Comment: you have only one variable, how do you expect it to hold references to several objects?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the "setterGetterClass" variable in every iteration of your for loop. When your loop ends, your "setterGetterClass" will have the last value of your JSONArray. That is the reason you get every time the last value. If you want to fetch all values, then you should add them to a list or similar structure. For example:

```
JSONArray json = req.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
List<SuperHeroe> superHeroeList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {    
SuperHeroe superHeroe = new SuperHeroe(jsonOb.getInt(Configg.TAG_rank),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_country),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_population),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_flag));
superHeroeList.add(superHeroe);
}
```

Then you'll have all the objects contained in the "superHeroeList" ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You for loop iterates & every time it initializes a new `SuperHeroes` instance to `setterGetterClass`. So after last iteration it will hold the last JsobObject data. Try

- Create an `ArrayList`.

  ```
  ArrayList<SuperHeroes> superHeroesList = new ArrayList<SuperHeroes>();
  ```
- Inside your `for` loop

  ```
  SuperHeroes superHeroes = new SuperHeroes(jsonOb.getInt(Configg.TAG_rank),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_country),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_population),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_flag);
  superHeroesList.add(superHeroes);
  ```

Now `superHeroesList` will have all your json objects.